# How to determine which cell is being viewed or clicked in a collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to be able to edit records that are displayed in a collection view.

I've added an "Edit" button to the collection view. What is the best way to determine which cell is to be edited?

I thought of doing something like so:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
 visibleCell = collectionView.visibleCells().first as MessageCell
}
```

I didn't want to add the edit button to the xib itself as I don't want the button to scroll when the cell scrolls

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to have a variable in your ViewController called something like `isEditing`. This will be set to true when the edit button is clicked.

Then, set your collection view's delegate to `self`.

Implement this method: `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`, A UICollectionViewDelegate method.

In the method, write something like:

```
if isEditing{
    // What happens when selected and editing
} else{
    // What happens when selected and not editing
}
```